# SAS Proc Report and Proc Template

Tags: sas

My aim is to produce a report as shown below:
[image]

I almost got it right with ods style 'Journal'. Here's my code and a screenshot of the output that I got.

```
ods rtf file="C:\Documents and Settings\trainee1\Desktop\table.rtf" bodytitle style=Journal;
    options nodate nonumber ls=250 ps=300;
    title1 justify =left height =1 font= 'Courier New' c=black "XXXX  Pharmaceuticals Corp" justify = right "Draft";   
    title2 justify =left height =1 font= 'Courier New' c=black "Protocol 5326-02"  j=right 'Page !{thispage} of !{lastpage}';
    title3  justify=center font="Courier new" height=1 "Listing 14.1.3" ;
    title4  justify=center font="Courier new" height=1 "Subject Demographic and Baseline Characteristics by Dose Level";
    title5  justify=center font="Courier new" height=1 "Safety Population";
    footnote1   justify=left font="Courier new" height=1    "Dose Level:  A=14mg qd, B=14mg bid, C=35mg qd, D=35mg bid";
    footnote2   "";
    footnote3   justify=left font="Courier new" height=1    "Cross Reference:  CRF page 3";
    footnote4   justify=left font="Courier new" height=1    "MM/DD/YYYY, XXXXX.sas ";
    ods escapechar= '!';
proc report data = final nowindows headskip missing split="/"         
        style(header)={just=left vjust=bottom protectspecialchars=off asis=on rules=none} 
         style(column)={axis=on }
       ;

    columns CHARA STAT ("Dose Level A (N=XX)" ACTIVE_A PLACEBO_A) ("Dose Level B (N=XX)" ACTIVE_B PLACEBO_B)
            ("Dose Level C (N=XX)" ACTIVE_C PLACEBO_C);
    define CHARA / display "Characteristics" left ;
    define STAT / display "Statistic" left ;
    define ACTIVE_A /display   "STA-5326/  N (%)" ;
    define PLACEBO_A /display   "placebo/  N (%)" ;
    define ACTIVE_B /display   "STA-5326/  N (%)" ;
    define PLACEBO_B /display   "placebo/  N (%)" ;
    define ACTIVE_C /display   "STA-5326/  N (%)" ;
    define PLACEBO_C /display   "placebo/  N (%)" ;

run;
ods rtf close;
```

[image]

And it was almost correct except for the font and fontsize. So I wrote a proc template to create a new style with Journal as the parent.

```
proc template; 
define style Styles.Custom; 
parent = Styles.Journal; 
replace fonts / 
    'TitleFont' = ("Courier New",8pt) /* Titles from TITLE statements */
    'TitleFont2' = ("Courier New",8pt) /* Procedure titles ("The _____ Procedure")*/
    'StrongFont' = ("Courier New",8pt) 
    'EmphasisFont' = ("Courier New",8pt) 
    'headingEmphasisFont' = ("Courier New",8pt) 
    'headingFont' = ("Courier New",8pt) /* Table column and row headings */
    'docFont' = ("Courier New",8pt) /* Data in table cells */
    'footFont' = ("Courier New",8pt) /* Footnotes from FOOTNOTE statements */ 
    'FixedEmphasisFont' = ("Courier New",8pt) 
    'FixedStrongFont' = ("Courier New",8pt) 
    'FixedHeadingFont' = ("Courier New",8pt) 
    'BatchFixedFont' = ("Courier New",8pt) 
    'FixedFont' = ("Courier New",8pt); 
end;
run;
```

and when the custom style that I created, this is what I get. Do level B and Dose level C gets pushed down. Actualy I am only reducing the size of the fonts and by my assumptinn I should have more space. What am I doing wrong? How do I correct this?

[image]

Comment: Courier New as a monospace font takes up a LOT more room than a proportionally spaced font.  Look at how wide those columns are.  Do you have flexibility to switch to Landscape perhaps?

Comment: yes. Please tell me what to do.

Comment: Try using `options orientation=landscape;`. As Joe mentions you may get better results with a different font.